# how to remove the white edge?

Tags: rendering

I use different ways to render my character and scene. I separate two different layers to render the character and scene. Then use *Alpha over* to combine two layers.

[image]

However, there is a white edge between character and scene

[image].

Comment: some possibilities: the white line already exists on your character. Your "cut out" is too big. Providing a blend file would help

Comment: how to provide a blender file?

Comment: Dilate/erode node in compositor